# Assigning this to inner variable say ""self

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, knockout.js

I am seeing in a lot of books and online coding tutorials suggesting to store variable "this" to an inner variable of a function especially while using Javascript. Can someone give a brief explanation on this.

TIA.

Comment: http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this . Scroll to "Common pitfalls".

Comment: [Scope and 'this'](http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback